# how to make a filled arch in blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, uv, objects

I have a super problem, I'm a beginner in blender, about 2 weeks, and I wanted to make an arch, but only it should be filled and with rounded edges, I was able to make the arch itself, but there were problems with the rounding. I just created an arch point by point, filled it inside and did an extrusion, everything would be fine, but now I need to somehow round off the edges and here everything is not going according to plan, I don't know if there is any normal way to do this, then what I ended up with when using the surface subdivision modifier - it's just awful, it's impossible to do uv, please help me, I searched the entire Internet and did not find anything.
I also tried to use bevel along the edges, but nothing worked, since there is no geometry in the filled place.

[image: arch]

[image: arch]

[image: arch]

[image: arch]

Comment: why did you apply a Subdivision Surface modifier? did you have a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to smooth out the mesh. To do that you can do shade smooth, which can be accessed by selecting the mesh and 2 finger clicking, which will give you a menu that has shade smooth as an option. You can also search "shade smooth" in the search menu (relatively new as well so not sure what it's called).

Comment: Yes, I did smooth shading, but it does not smooth out much, I would like to round the edges, but without the geometry inside, nothing happens, it starts to break

Comment: What are you referring to, when you say "without the geometry inside"? Shade smooth essentially tries to "average out" the mesh using the vertices you have, so if you want the edges to be rounder, you can probably remove some of the vertices .

Comment: I mean one big polygon, in the middle, I built an arch point by point and then filled it

Comment: You can delete the faces you don't want, and then select the edges of the new face that you want. Then you can press F to fill the edges to create a plane.